# How to specify the file path for the private file system?

Tags: 8

Environment: Shared hosting, Apache.

Home directory: **/home/someuser**

Website at: **/home/someuser/public_html/stuff**

I've spent 2 days trying to get this to work, and realise that as soon as I'm answered it will be blindingly obvious, but I'm failing miserably right now.

I have created a directory in my public_html directory called **private_files** with a sub-directory called **stuff**. Both have access rights 755.

I have edited settings.php to include the line:

```
# $settings['file_private_path'] 
= '/home/someuser/public_html/private_files/stuff';
```

I have cleared all caches.

The file system configuration page shows:

> Private file system path
>
> Not set

What stunningly stupid mistake am I making? Why is what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the line in settings.php verbatim, or have you removed the comment char (`#`)?

Comment: @Clive I told you it would be blindingly stupid -- after 2 days of trying I'd pretty well gone gaga (and I rarely do anything with PHP anyway -- it's all monkey see monkey do something stupid). If you want to construct an answer pointing out my idiot mistake, I'll accept it -- somebody else might fall into the same idiot trap.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over it. Every programmer ever has been through similar things. It's a right of passage. That's what makes the community so great - we can all look stupid to each other, and since we've all done it, we're all ok!

Answer (score 4):

In order for this question to be marked as answered, @Clive pointed out [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267909/how-to-specify-the-file-path-for-the-private-file-system#comment328473_267909) that the problem was the leading `#` character, which made the 1st line a comment, meaning that the `file_private_path` was never set.

The correct line should be

```
$settings['file_private_path'] = '/home/someuser/public_html/private_files/stuff';
```